# Well-made vagrant box for Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, virtualbox, vagrant

I am currently using [a vagrant box provided among cloud images for Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/saucy/current/saucy-server-cloudimg-i386-vagrant-disk1.box), but it has a number of issues I would like to avoid, relative for instance to the ["official" vagrant image for 12.04 from Vagrant](http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box):

- It has a single root partition covering the entire disk, and no swap, instead of using LVM and having swap preconfigured. That's not fixable by simple provisioning, as far as I can tell, since one would need to reboot to some separate Linux distribution, repartition, and reboot again. (I don't think I can loop-mount VM image from the host, since they aren't raws - but more importantly, that would defeat the point of VMs, and for instance not work on my OS X host).
- No CDROM drive is preconfigured, so installing the guest additions from VirtualBox does not work directly (the drive can be added VBoxManage, but if I make VM do that in the customization section, it gets re-executed at each boot, which does not work).
- linux-generic is not installed - this gave some funny errors when compiling external modules (from VirtualBox guest additions): they would compile but not load, because they depend on modules which are part of `linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic`. Only once you find this problem, fixing it is rather easy.

How can I fix this?
My favorite solution would be a high-quality Vagrant box for Ubuntu 13.10 (preferably 32bit), but better ways to fix the above problems are also accepted.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to build your own base boxes. Good tools for automating it are [Packer](http://www.packer.io/) and [veewee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee).

There are a lot of templates around, but one good starting point is the [Bento](https://github.com/opscode/bento) project. You can customize the preseed and other configuration scripts to your need.